# JQuery addClass SyntaxError: Unexpected token illegal

Tags: jquery, addclass

What's wrong with my JQuery code? In chromium browser, I get the **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"** in using JQuery addClass. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url = window.location.href;
  $('ul.menu li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var suburl = $this.find('a').attr('href');
    if(url.indexOf(suburl) > 0) {
      $this.addClass("active");​ // **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**
      //alert("url=" + url + ", suburl=" + suburl);
    }
  });

  $("button").click(function(){
    $("ul.nav a.active").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<p>List<p>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="/test/jq_test.html">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a href="/test/jq_test1.html">Milk</a></li>
  <li><a href="/test/jq_test2.html">Tea</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an illegal character after the `;`  Copy to notepadd++ and you will see it

```
if(url.indexOf(suburl) > 0) {
  $this.addClass("active");? // <-- delete this
  //alert("url=" + url + ", suburl=" + suburl);
  }
});
```

Delete it and it should work